# .desktop arduino file killed system

Tags: boot, system-installation, crash, source-packages

any idea on what happened? i went here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

downloaded the 64 bit for my os (running ubuntu gnome 14.04 LTS). and then I chmod +x the ./install.sh (not sure if this is bad) and run it...says creating desktop stuff etc etc.

I click .desktop and system flips out. All files loose gui visuals and every time i boot if i Run ANYTHING it crashes saying exiting powertop. Only thing I can think of is maybe it added something to my rc.local somehow. plz help :(